# How to run test sample contract in the standard web browser?

Tags: mix, javascript, browsers

I've got the Sample contract within Mix IDE which seems fine within embedded web browser.

[image: Mix IDE - Sample Ratings]

However when go to the same URL appearing in *Mix* embedded page using Chrome web-browser (e.g. `http://localhost:54614/index.html`), it opens fine, but when I'm trying to store some values, I've got the error:

> index.html:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Sample' of undefined

I believe it's missing *web3.js* (since it's not loaded from the source) and probably other things.

How do I solve these dependencies and integrate my sample project to run the page using a standard web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the point. Today you can't use Dapps with standard browsers but only with Ethereum enabled browsers. The only widely used one for now is Mist.

But there are works in progress to create browser extensions (see [metamask.io](https://metamask.io/)) to add the ability for standard browser to run Dapps. 
However you will probably have to wait perhaps until Ethereum Serenity release.

Comment: You can also check out https://metamask.io/, which will be another alternative host mechanism for Dapps, but within existing browsers.

Comment: @BobSummerwill That's what I was talking about but I always forget the name of your extension and was to lazy to search on my phone... Hopefully you're here to comment, I will edit my answer :)